# NodeJS - res.sendFile gives html code but not loading/rendering that html

Tags: express

I am very new to NodeJs. I am using express module in NodeJS and trying to load html files through sendFile command. While doing it my first sendfile command works well, however it doesnt work well for second sendFile command. Can anyone please let me know whats going wrong here?

```
 var express = require('express');

 var app = express();
 var path = require('path');

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
 });

 app.get('/unpack', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/main.html'));
 });
```

In the above code the below line works well

```
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
```

Problem lies with

```
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/main.html'));
```

Comment: have you tried to console.log the path so formed by `path.join(__dirname, 'public/main.html')` is actually the correct path for the html file.

Comment: I don't think that first `sendFile` (for `/`) is ever going to get hit, considering that requests for it will most likely get served by `express.static()`. Also, _"doesn't work well"_ is quite a vague problem description...

Comment: @robertklep: Sorry about vague problem description. It doesn't render that  html. However res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')); code renders the index.html page very well.

Comment: @warl0ck: yes I just did the console.log in the code where /unpack method is called. it gives main.html's code in log.

Comment: Oh hang on: are you requesting `/unpack` through AJAX/XHR?

Comment: @robertklep: yes

Comment: AJAX provides a method of retrieving data _while staying on the same page_. If you want the HTML content to replace the current page, you're going to need additional code to make that happen. A quick and dirty solution would be `document.write(theResponseHTML)`.

Comment: aaha...right...so instead of AJAX what can be used?

Comment: @KTB that really depends on what exactly it is that you want to do. If you want to post data to `/unpack`, it could be as simple as a normal form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @warl0ck and @robertklep for your response. As @robertklep mentioned in the comments section my problem was that I was using AJAX to call /unpack hence I was getting the response as html code. This helps me to understand the problem and I will change AJAX to something else.

Thanks @warl0ck and @robertklep again!!!

-kt